# Appcelerator Cloud Reset Password default page, users reset password, nothing happens

Tags: android, ios, titanium, appcelerator, reset-password

I've had an appcelerator app on the store for over 2 years, no issues with any user resetting their password until a few months ago.  When users reset their password in my app, they receive an email with a link and clicking that takes them to the appcelerator reset password page.  When entering a new password, and clicking submit it just reloads the page and does not renew their password.

I have tried using the default email template instead of the custom one I was using, and still the same issue.  anyone else run into this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Testing this again today, it magically appears to have fixed itself!